# How to open a latex table in R (as dataframe)

Tags: r, dplyr, import

Suppose I have the following table (as a Tex file)

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
variables & group a & group b & diff \\ \midrule
x         & a11     & b12     & d13  \\
y         & a21     & b22     & d23  \\
z         & a31     & b32     & d33  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there any package or way to open this as a dataframe in R?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read.delim` directly:

```
> dat <- read.delim(text="variables & group a & group b & diff \\ 
  x         & a11     & b12     & d13  \\
  y         & a21     & b22     & d23  \\
  z         & a31     & b32     & d33  \\ ", sep="&", comment.char = "\\")
> dat
   variables   group.a   group.b   diff
1 x           a11       b12       d13  
2 y           a21       b22       d23  
3 z           a31       b32       d33
```

Just remove `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`